# Descriptive icons in Eclipse's Package Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a project with multiple types of entities in the same package. Most are normal java classes but there are also interfaces (IArithmeticExpression.java) and enums (MulDiv.java) in there. This is a view from the Package Explorer in my project:

[image: From my Package Explorer view]

I've seen in instructional videos that some people have adornments on the icons indicating the type of file; I for interface in this screenshot from a video:

[image: Screenshot from an instructional video]

How can I configure Eclipse to do this? I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Preferences and go to 'General > Appearance > Label Decorations'.

Select the 'Java Type Indicator' decoration to get these.